# Plus sign (+ literal) in url to rewrite with mod_rewrite.. How?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite an url with mod_rewrite.
Problem is the url to be rewritten contans a literal + (plus) sign, and that's also the delimiter for the vars I need to get from the url...

Current url's:
www.domain.com/page/756/no/Plumbers+London/

I want the part "Plumbers+London" to be taken and rewritten as:

New url's:
domain.com/pages/Plumbers/London/

Tried this but it doesn't work:

RewriteRule page/(.*)/no/(.*)\+(.*)/ /pages/$2/$3/ [R=301,L]

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any way to change the delimiter? You can't change the empty space being encoded as `+` but if you can change the delimiter to another character your problem would be a lot easier to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the delimiter.

Ah simple mistake.

The dot (.) matches the full URI by itself, or it matches any **single** character.
Try changing it to:

```
RewriteRule page/(.*)/no/(.*)\+(.*)/ /pages/$2/$3 [R=301,L]
```

(My regex is a bit rusty, but I believe that will do the trick.)
Perhaps use a non-greedy operator: (.*?)